# Dynamically render checkboxes and handle change events: React+Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, semantic-ui-react

I am creating dynamic checboxes based on an array of objects but I am unable to set change handlers for the same . I am using semantic-ui-react Checkboxes. How do I handle change events for the corresponding change checkboxes.

Also There is a submit button , I need to get items that are checked .Can someone help me with this too

Help would be appreciated

### Checkbox render code

```
    let arr = [  {key: "Pending", text: "Pending", checked: false}
         {key: "Approved", text: "Approved", checked: false}
         {key: "Cancelled", text: "Cancelled", checked: false}
    ];

    this.state ={ optionsArr: [] }

    {this.state.arr.map((item: any, i: number) => (
                      <div className="menu-item" key={i}>
                        <Checkbox
                          name={item.text}
                          onChange={this.handleItemClick}
                          checked={item.checked}
                          label={item.text}
                        />
                      </div>
      ))}
```

### Change Handler

```
     handleItemClick = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, data: any) => {
        const i = this.state.optionsArr.findIndex(
          (item: any) => item.text === data.name
        );
        const optionsArr = this.state.optionsArr.map((prevState: any, si: any) =>
          si === i ? !prevState : prevState
        );
        this.setState({ optionsArr });
      };
```

Comment: Can you add a whole file?

Comment: The first time you loop through the optionsArr, you use `item.text` on each item. The second time you loop through, if `si === i` you try to return `!item`. I'm not sure that makes sense, think you want to return `{text: prevState.text, checked: !prevState.checked}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you are returning the wrong thing when trying to update the state of the options array.

`prevState` is an object, like `{key: 'string', text: 'string', checked: boolean}`, so doing `!prevState` doesn't make sense.
 Try:

```
     handleItemClick = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, data: any) => {
        const i = this.state.optionsArr.findIndex(
          (item: any) => item.text === data.name
        );
        const optionsArr = this.state.optionsArr.map((prevState: any, si: any) =>
          si === i ? {...prevState, checked: !prevstate.checked} : prevState
        );
        this.setState({ optionsArr });
      };
```

You can get the checked items by using filter:

```
this.state.optionsArr.filter((item: any) => item.checked)
```

Comment: Use filter. Updated my answer

Comment: store the original state in the state object also. Then you can call `this.setState({optionsArr: this.state.original})`

Comment: That would give me all checkoxes unchecked as I am setting it to false in the begining. I want the previous state

Comment: What have you tried? I'm sure you can come up with something to store the previous state...